# Dynamic Polulate MYSQL TableFrom Other Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables as under

**oilchangehistory**

```
histID  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
oilChangeDate   date    YES         
custID  varchar(45) YES         
VIN varchar(45) YES         
invoiceNo   int(11) YES         
incentive   int(11) YES         
promotion   int(11) YES         
cashPaid    int(11) YES
```

**invoice**

```
invoiceNo   int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
invoiceDate timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
amount  int(11) YES         
subTotal    int(11) YES         
tax int(11) YES         
others  int(11) YES         
totalDue    int(11) YES         
cashReceived    int(11) YES         
itemQty int(11) YES         
salePrice   int(11) YES         
itemName    varchar(45) NO  MUL     
litre   decimal(6,2)    NO          
VIN varchar(45) NO  MUL     
custID  varchar(45) NO          
incentive   int(11) YES         
promotion   int(11) YES
```

now I want that when I entered data into invoice table as data entered in **invoice table** the **oilchangehistory** table populate at that time how to use procedure or trigger for this please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the exact values from invoice table to oilchangehistory table, Instead of creating oilchangehistory as a table create as a view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW oilchangehistory
                SELECT CURDATE() AS oilchangedate
                      ,custid
                      ,vin
                      ,invoiceno
                      ,incentive
                      ,promotion
                      ,cashreceived as cashpaid
                 FROM invoice;
```

If you dont want to create a view, use Trigger to populate the oilchangehistory table.
A stored procedure is a user defined piece of code written in the local version of PL/SQL, which may return a value (making it a function) that is invoked by calling it explicitly.
A trigger is a stored procedure that runs automatically when various events happen (eg update, insert, delete).

A trigger fires after an insert, update, or delete automatically. A stored procedure is a server-side program that is run when you invoke it. so go for trigger in this case.

Comment: respected i want to use trigger or procedure but don't how?